# Set context on Google Actions through Dialogflow fulfillment

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I'm using the Dialogflow editor fulfillment to build a conversation on Google Assistant, but I'm not sure how to use the `agent.setContext` function.
When I ask "Turn off my device" the first step returns successfully. The problem happens when the user responds with "TV", for example. The system returns with another context, ignoring the one I set.
When the user directly asks "Turn off my TV in the kitchen" the system also works perfectly. Because of it I think that the entities are correctly defined.

**Conversation 1** *(success)*:

- Turn off my TV in the kitchen
- Right. Turning off.

**Conversation 2** *(fail)*:

- Turn off my device //Gives the same intent that Conversation 1
- OK, which device?
- TV
- "My bot" isn't responding right now. Try again soon. //It throws "'final_response' must be set". I think it's because of generic intent actions.intent.TEXT.

My code:

The code below is nested in `exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest` and the intent is called by `intentMap.set('smarthome.device.switch.off', setDeviceOff);`

```
const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: request, response: response });

function setDeviceOff(agent) {
    const device = agent.parameters.device;
    const room   = agent.parameters.room;
    const context= 'device-switch'; //I tried 'smarthome.device.switch.off' too
      let resp = commandDevice(device, room, 'Off', agent, context);
      return resp;
}

function commandDevice(device, room, cmd, agent, context) {
    var conv = agent.conv();
    if(device===''){
        conv.ask("OK, which device?");
    }else if (room===''){
        conv.ask("Got it. of what room?");
    }else{
        conv.ask("Right. Turning off.");
    }
    agent.setContext({
        name:context,
        lifespan: 5, //Tried 0, 4 and 3 too
        parameters:{
            'device':device,
            'room':room
        }
    });
    agent.add(conv);
    return true;
}
```

So I tried another version and the same problem persists:

```
const app = dialogflow();
app.intent('welcome', conv =>{
   conv.ask("Welcome to auto obari. What can I do for you?"); 
});
app.intent('Default Fallback Intent',conv =>{
   conv.ask("I didn't understand, can you try again?"); 
});
app.intent('smarthome.device.switch.off', (conv,{device, room})=> {
    const context= 'device-switch';
    if(device===''){
        conv.ask("OK, which device?");
    }else if (room===''){
        conv.ask("Got it. of what room?");
    }else{
        conv.ask("Right. Turning off.");
    }
    const parameters = {'device':device, 'room': room};
    conv.contexts.set(context, 5, parameters);
});
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app); //I tried exports.factsAboutGoogle, but it threw a error too.
```

[image: The intent]

The contexts are the same, but the intent is different.
[image: The contexts are the same, but the intent is different.]

Comment: Could you please also share the logs of the firebase cloud function or the node js server, whichever you are using?

Comment: On Google Functions the executions finished with status code 200, without any errors. On Google Actions the given error is "MalformedResponse: 'final_response' must be set". "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response Via: 1.1 google Alt-Svc"

I think it's because the intent is not being fired again when the user responds with "TV". The intent sent is the generic "actions.intent.TEXT".

Comment: I put more details with the logs on the question.

Comment: I tried to set a function to get the actions.intent.TEXT and the intent is not called. I really don't know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If using `conv`, you may also try like this:

```
app.intent('<INTENT>', conv => {
  conv.ask('<RESPONSE>');
  const parameters = {'param1':param1, 'param2': param2}};
  conv.contexts.set('welcome-context', 5, parameters);
});
```

and access it like [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/lib-v1-migration) :

```
const conv.contexts.get(<context>).parameters[<param>];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But the same problems persists. I put my new code above.

Comment: I tried the `const device = conv.contexts.get('device-switch').parameters.device;` format too.

Comment: did you check the documentation?

Comment: I read everything I could and I got the code above. The only difference I found from the documentation is in the "exports" function. But when I use factsAboutGoogle in Dialogflow, an error is displayed.

Comment: try a fresh project and add code one step at a time. start from a simple 1 liner message to your current version. see if that works.

Comment: I found out that the contexts are the same, but the intent is changed. From the documentation I found an example that is very close of what I used on the question, but I also tried to do it and the intent keeps changing even the example not expecting that.

Comment: context's life depends upon the lifespan you set and not on the intent triggered. the intent is triggered based on context or on the event.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method too it worked for me

```
const AppContexts = {CONTEXT_ONE: 'context-one'};
const app = dialogflow();

In current intent (for output context)
conv.contexts.set(AppContexts.CONTEXT_ONE, 1);

In next intent (for input context )
const context = conv.contexts.get(AppContexts.CONTEXT_ONE);
```